# How can I list all my posts both deleted and nondeleted?

Tags: support, search

How can I list all my posts both deleted and nondeleted?

In the search box of main site:

```
user:674 deleted:yes
```

only shows deleted posts.

```
user:674 deleted:yes deleted:no
```

doesn't list both deleted posts and non-deleted posts, but only non-deleted posts.

Does SE deliberately make reasonable operations involving  deleted posts hard?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing the search engine simply reads the options in the order they were given. So the second `deleted:no` overwrites the first `deleted:yes`. This is also why `user:674 deleted:no deleted:yes` will only return deleted posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about the *correct* syntax for doing searches with `deleted:`, but putting *any* string after `deleted:` which is *not* `yes` or `no` seems to work.

For example

```
user:674 deleted:*
```

I don't think there is any deliberate attempt at obfuscation involved here.

I'm at this very moment not 100% sure that deleted posts stay around forever.  Someone with more knowledge than me will supply that information, I'm sure.

Comment: In searching, I've come up with https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile , which I'd never noticed before, and also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted which was linked to from the FAQ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: IIRC the only posts that were permanently deleted were those which were purged from the database - that hoax rm -rf / post on SF, some legendary joke posts on SO and so on.

Answer (score 10):

If you look in the help the full list of search operators is covered there. The page is titled: [help/searching](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

> Deleted Posts (requires 10,000 reputation) When you earn the Access to
>   Moderator Tools privilege, you may search your own deleted posts by
>   using the deleted: operator.
>
> - deleted:1 searches only your deleted posts
> - deleted:all searches both deleted and not-deleted posts that you've authored
> - deleted:0 searches only not-deleted posts that you've authored (effectively the same as user:me)

Unfortunately this operator appears to be limited to users with 10k rep or higher for searching amongst all the deleted posts. User's can however see their own deleted posts, they just cannot search for them using the `deleted:` operator.

#### References

- [Enable searching with deleted:1 for 10k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users)
- [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

Comment: I believe you can always see your deleted posts; the FAQ had wording like "always visible to the author"

Comment: @JeffSchaller you can see them but you can't search them. I just tested with a sock account that has posted a deleted question and searching for `user:NNN deleted:all` returns nothing.